# Multiple Condition

Tags: vba, excel

I have "object doesn't support this method" error when trying to do a comparison of column cross sheets. . If both column A and B in sheet 1 matches both column A and B in sheet 2, it will display the match in sheet 3.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code. Paste the code into the question, highlight it and use the `{}` button to format. You need to use `If a = b And c = d Then`. `&` is a concatenation operator in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

There were a number of issues in your code. In the future, please post the actual code (not screenshot).

1. Watch out for "And" vs "&" in your if statement.
2. ".value" not ".values" in your vars.
3. "Dim as string" since we're working with the cell.
4. "Worksheet." not "Worksheets."
5. I don't think you need a "Set" for these. (could be wrong)

Try the code below, it works for me. You may need to modify the lines writing to the "match" sheet.

```
Sub find()

Dim a As String
Dim b As String
Dim c As String
Dim d As String

a = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1").Value
b = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("a1").Value
c = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("b1").Value
d = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("b1").Value

If a = b And c = d Then

Worksheets("match").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = c
Worksheets("match").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = c

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: the variables a to d could be numbers. Unless one knows that they are text they better be declared as Variants. the `Set` key word must be used with objects, such as a range. `Set a = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1").Value` will cause an error "Object required" because `.Value` isn't an object. `Set a =Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1")` will assign the range object to the variable `a` if `a` is declared as a range as it originally was. Comparing `a = b` while both are ranges probably works because the Value property is the default of the range object, but it is terribly bad syntax.

Comment: `c` will need to remain as a `Range` object so that the OP's assignment using `c.Offset(0, 2).Value` will work (your code just sets the final assignment using `c`)

Comment: Great points @Variatus. I'm reading up on my [range objects](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/range-object.html) since it's been a while.